# P2p to find other clients (for distributed computing project)

Tags: protocols, p2p, distributed-computing

I would like to ask you experts for some advice.
For a distributed computing project of mine I use BOINC, but the BOINC clients don't "see" each other. So everyone is computing its own workunit.

What do youthink using p2p techniques for this so thatthe clients can find each other and group together to work on one bigger workunit. I know that internetconnection is the bottleneck, but some tasks can't be computed on just one hosts and need some sort of cluster.

So I would even start learning to code in c/c++ to bring p2p to BOINC. What p2p protocoll do you think suits best, or should we start from skretch?
and what else do you think?

I would start to code how clients can find each other.

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a book called Practical JXTA II which is available online from Scribd. It contains general chapters about P2P. You may want to take a look at it for inspiration.

There are miscellaneous frameworks available. You need to investigate what fits your needs best. Warning: writing something from scratch is a lot of work.

Comment: hi, I had a look at http://www.scribd.com/doc/47538921/Practical-JXTA-II and I'm not quite sure, if that is what I need. And I'm more a practical guy, I need a lot of axamples to code something :).

Comment: I was pointing it as a starting point. You may want to explore JGroups too.